# Use Raspberry Pi to power a low noise inverting amplifier with negative voltage input

Tags: power-supply, batteries

I am looking to use a Raspberry Pi to power and read the current from a current-to-voltage converter. I am currently using two batteries to power the operational amplifier, as shown in the schematic below. Please ignore the potentiometer, it is an attempt at mimicing a sensor and is for illistrative purposes only. I would like to measure the current going through the sensor.

[image: Constant Voltage Schematic]

However, I am finding that the 9V batteries I'm using to give the op-amp a negative voltage are running low pretty quickly, so I would like to power the op amp through the Raspberry Pi.

The sensor has a constant voltage input of 50 mV and a variation in output voltage from the op amp of 1 mV (even with the gain). The sensor is similar to a thermocouple or resistance temperature detector in terms of its small changes in current.

I am unsure if using a resistance divider or similar (as shown here: http://tangentsoft.net/elec/vgrounds.html) will wash out the signal. E.g. Voltage division with 2.5 V going into the op amp when I'm looking for mV changes.

Is there a way to redesign the circuit to operate from a single supply voltage source? Thanks!

Comment: "Is there a way to redesign the circuit to operate from a single supply voltage source?" That would depend on whether or not you need to measure current flowing in either direction. So - do you?

Comment: Not really, I'm looking to measure current flowing in one direction only.

Comment: What is the sensor's internal resistance?

Comment: @BruceAbbott the sensor's internal resistance is approximately 5kΩ.